# type mismatch cannot convert from boolean to string

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new at this and is the first time I try to do an android app. I'm trying to do a rock, paper & scissors. I'm having some error....

Comment: Whatever clarity there was in the original question, after the edit it is gone. Please re-phrase your question, and provide a code sample illustrating the "some error..." part.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fill String variable with boolean value.

You might want to add another variable, called:

```
boolean isComputerPlay = true;
```

and use this variable to store the state.

Comment: you can use `boolean boolData = String.valueOf(booleanVar);` for that